# How to build the florist library with GNAT?

Tags: ada, gnat

I am trying to build the florist library on a linux (mint) system.
The source was cloned from github, and the instructions to install it were followed.

It compiles fine (with two warnings for depreciated issues). But the build process terminates with a problem:

```
Build Libraries
   [gprlib]       florist.lexch
   [archive]      libflorist.a
   [index]        libflorist.a
gprlib: could not copy ALI files to library directory
gprbuild: could not build library for project florist
[2022-02-20 17:04:34] process exited with status 4, 100% (81/81), elapsed time: 04.17s
```

I am using the GPS 19 and build from there.

Any idea's on how to fix this?

Comment: (1) Given that you're building with GPS 19, did you actually build the [19-sustained](https://github.com/AdaCore/florist/tree/19-sustained) branch? (2) You can increase the verbosity level of GRPbuild by adding the `-vh` option to the `GPRBUILD_FLAGS` in the make file (`Makefile`). This might give some additional information. (3) If still no success, then please add the version numbers of GPRbuild and GNAT (output of `gprbuild --version` and `gnat --version`), plus the actual build commands used, to the question.

Comment: Thank you DeeDee, it turned out to be way simpler than that: access rights. I just used the command line (sudo gprbuild in the florist top level directory) and it works like a charm. - I am still rather new to linux...

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple matter of access right. GPS runs in the user domain.
Using grpbuild in the top level florist directory as 'sudo grpbuild' did complete the build.